# How to make only some url [other than mydomain] in my webview app open in browser?

Tags: android-studio

I would like to make any url other than my domains url to be opened in browser, for example if the user clicks a link like "https://www.google.com/(variable)" in my webview app , it should be opened in their browser not inside my webapp.

Please help me to do so In Kotlin